# Which version of Visual Studio Express for JScript .NET?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-express, jscript.net

Which version of the Express edition of Visual Studio can I use to work with Windows Forms programs written in JScript .NET? I did a quick search and I can see versions for Visual Basic, Visual C# and Visual C++ ... but not JScript.

Up until now I've just been editing in Notepad and compiling using jsc.exe, but debugging is starting to become a real pain. I'd like to be able to step through my code and locate the exact location of a bug.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can write JScript code in any version of Visual Studio you want. For the Express editions, [Visual Web Developer Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-Web-Developer) is a good choice.

The catch is that you cannot *compile* JScript code in the Visual Studio IDE. You have to perform this step either from the command line or via the ASP.NET page.

See MSDN for more details: [Writing, Compiling, and Debugging JScript Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw8ace91.aspx)

Comment: What about Windows Forms? Can you create GUIs using the drag-and-drop Toolbox like you normally can for the other languages?

Comment: @posfan12: I'm not really sure what you're talking about. Yes, you can create Windows Forms applications using the drag-and-drop toolbox in Visual Studio. Not in the Web Developer edition, though. There are no "Windows Forms" on the Web. This also doesn't have anything to do with JScript. Remember, though, that you can download and install *multiple* versions of VS Express, if you need the various functionality.

Comment: It is relevant as you can create Windows Forms applications with JScript .NET. And, if the Web Developer edition does not support this, then there's a good reason not to use it.

Comment: For additional clarity, I am *not* working with ASP.NET pages *or* creating a command-line program. It is a Windows Forms program.

Comment: Step #4 in the first section of "Debugging JScript with Visual Studio" also fails for me. See my comments on that page. There's no way to select an EXE file as the project/solution file in the Express Editions as far as I can tell.

Comment: @posfan12: Well, you got me there. I didn't know you could write WinForms apps in JScript. I certainly haven't done it myself. I just assumed you were working on a web app. That's good to know. However, I *know* you can compile to an EXE using the Express Editions of VS. I've actually done that before. It makes sense that you can't with the Web Developer edition, but C#/VB.NET/C++ all can. I can't say if they support JScript, though. Weird that no one else has come along with more experience here.